# iOS app that sends a push notification when native alarm goes off

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, apple-push-notifications, push

I'm wondering if there is a way to have an app send a push notification when it notices the regular clock app alarm goes off.  Is there a way to do this or at least "spy" on the native alarm app so my app can know when it goes off?

Answer (score 1):

In iOS, apps are "sandboxed", so they don't "talk" with each other. The only way they can interact (in a very restricted way) is if they share a part of their App ID. As the stock clock app is made by Apple, there's no way your app will ever have access to data from the stock apps.

Also your app can not send a push notification its only a server that can do that. you can send a request to your own server , for sending the Push notification to some other device, but not directly.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Alright that's what I figured.  Thank you!  I would upvote you if I could